# Why MD5 hashing is being frequently used for preventing of loading of outdated CSS, JavaScript and media files?

Tags: webpack, gulp, md5

I understand why we need to make the names of CSS, JavaScript and media files like images unique when building the project for production. I don't understand why the using of MD5 for this effect reaching is so popular, for example:

- [In Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/guides/caching/#root)
- [In Gulp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-revision)

To generate the filename like `main.7e2c49a622975ebd9b7e.js`, we need to read the file and create the MD5 has of the content. Seems like it will take a lot of time, especially in HD images and videos case.

There are some other alternatives how to generate the unique file name:

1. Using the UNIX timestamp
2. Using the `Math.random()`

Just two instances, but I don't see the reason to explore more.

Comment: The benefit of using the hash of the file is that we can quickly tell that nothing about the file has changed, even if it was created/uploaded at a later time. If you change one file then re-build/deploy your project, every other file is still valid and their cached versions can still be used. If we had used the compile/pack timestamp, they would be treated as new files.

Comment: How would the unix timestamp tell you if the newly generated file is different? If the contents are the same but the timestamp is different that doesnt really tell you if its outdated or not. The md5 hash does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A primary reason is that if the files contents don't change, the hash won't change. And if the hash doesn't change that means your users' browsers won't have to download the files after your next deployment (as the browser has cached the file from a previous pageload).

If you used timestamp, every filename would change for every deployment, resulting in your users' browsers having to redownload *every* file in your project...even files whose content did not change. This can have a hugely negative performance hit if you are deploying code frequently.